# Hibernate Criteria API equivalent for "elements()"

Tags: hibernate, criteria

Is it possible to implement the following query using Criteria API?

```
select order from ORDER as order,ITEM as item 
where item.itemID like 'ITM_01' and item in elements(order.items)
```

Answer (score 3):

To answer the question in the title - no, there's no direct equivalent for `elements()` in Criteria API.

However, your query's use of `elements()` is superfluous. It can instead be more simply rewritten as

```
select order from ORDER as order
  where order.items.itemID like 'ITM_01'
```

Equivalent criteria would have to use nested criteria instance to access collection:

```
session.createCriteria(Order.class)
 .createCriteria("items")
 .add(Restrictions.like("itemID", "ITM_01"));
```

Another alternative is to use aliases:

```
session.createCriteria(Order.class)
 .createAlias("items", "item")
 .add(Restrictions.like("item.itemID", "ITM_01"));
```

Note that you don't need to use `LIKE` for fixed value, you can use simple equality instead.